# Function to remove data frames in a list of data frames based on name

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have a list of list of data frames named `Data_list` and I want to remove all the data frames **containing** "TAB" or "tab" in their full name. How can I deal with `lapply`, an anonymous function and `grepl` from the `dplyr` package ?

```
New_Data_list <- lapply(Data_list, function(x)x[names(x) != "Tab"])
```

Comment: grepl is a base R function i guess? you can try ```lapply(Data_list, function(x)x[,!grepl("tab|TAB",colnames(x))])```

Comment: This is not a case for lapply. Use `New_Data_list <- Data_list[!grepl("tab", names(Data_list), ignore.case = TRUE)]`

Comment: When you refer to "full names" are you referring to the name of the data frame in the list? rather than the names of the columns or variables in the data frames?

Comment: @Peter, yes it is the name of each data frame within a list

Comment: Does the proposed answer below work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### list with named data frames and list of named data frames

Using `purrr::map` and `lmap` to remove data frames conditionally by names when the list of data frames is a list object in a list, as suggested by comment to earlier answer:

#### data

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:2,
                 b = c("a", "b"))

df_ls2 <- list(df2 = df,
               df2tab = df,
               df2TABdf = df,
               TABdf2 = df,
               df2_5 = df)
               

df_ls <- list(df1 = df,
              df1tab = df,
              df1TABdf = df,
              TABdf1 = df,
              df1_3 = df, 
              df1_4 = df_ls2)
# df_ls
```

#### code

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)


  lmap(df_ls, function(x) x[!str_detect(names(x), "tab|TAB")]) %>% 
  map(function(x) x[!str_detect(names(x), "tab|TAB")])

#> $df1
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 2 b
#> 
#> $df1_3
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 2 b
#> 
#> $df1_4
#> $df1_4$df2
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 2 b
#> 
#> $df1_4$df2_5
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 2 b
```

#### comment

`lmap` removes named data frames in the list

`map` removes  named data frames from the child list of data frames

I've not checked whether this works for deeper nesting of lists of data frames.

#### List of named data frames

First answer for removing data frames conditionally where the list contains only  named data frames:

#### data

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:2,
                 b = c("a", "b"))

df_ls <- list(df1 = df,
              dftab = df,
              dfTABdf = df,
              TABdf = df,
              df3 = df)
# df_ls
```

#### code

```
library(stringr)

df_ls[!str_detect(names(df_ls), "tab|TAB")]
#> $df1
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 2 b
#> 
#> $df3
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 2 b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: First, thank you for your help. Indeed, it removes the data frames in `Data_list` that contain "Tab" or "TAB"  in their name. But `Data_list` is a list of 64 df's and I realise that some of them are lists of lists of data frames. In this precise case, the df's in the list of list that also contain "Tab" are not removed yet. I do not know whether it is clear

Comment: Have a look at the revised (second) answer which deals with the case of list of data frames within a list...

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base R with `grep()`

```
Data_list[grep("tab", names(Data_list), ignore.case = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]
```

or `grepl()` (also base R)

```
Data_list[!grepl("tab", names(Data_list), ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

Example data:

```
Data_list <- list(
  df_tab  = iris[1:2, 1:2],
  df_TAB  = iris[1:2, 3:5],
  df_good = iris[1:2, 4:5]
)
```